# Can't see products informations on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

here's my problem : 
I run a code on an application using Rails 4.1.6 and works perfectly. When I try to translate this code on my other application, the terminal does not give any error but the information from my table products do not appear. Like this (using rails 4.0.6) :

Products for sale

---

Nothing.

---

Nothing.

---

Nothing.

---

While they appear well on the other application, like this:

Products for sale

---

, description, price...

---

img, description, price...

---

img, description, price...

---

I can not find the problem , maybe someone already known that?

Edit :

(Using seeds.rb with command rake db:seed)

Edit :

```
1.9.3-p551 :002 > Product.pluck(:name)
   (1.3ms)  SELECT `products`.`name` FROM `products`  WHERE     `products`.`active` = 1
 => [nil, nil, nil]
```

my seeds.rb file :

```
Product.delete_all
Product.create(id: 1, name: 'Montages simples ikebana en chocolat',
            description:
            %{
            Créez des montages commerciaux simple et rapide pour mettre en valeur votre vitrine.
            },
            image_url: 'IMG_4543.JPG',
            price: 9.00,
           professor: 'avec Jérémy Fs', active: true)
Product.create(id: 2, name: 'Exemple 2',
           description:
           %{
           Miam miam.
           },
           image_url: 'prout.jpg',
           price: 'gratuit',
           professor: 'avec Jérémy Fs', active: true)
Product.create(id: 3, name: 'Exemple3',
           description:
           %{
           Miam miam2.
           },
           image_url: 'tomate_ronde_2.jpg',
           price: 'gratuit',
           professor: 'avec Jérémy Fs', active: true)
```

********_create_product.rb :

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :price, precision: 12, scale: 3
      t.boolean :active
      t.text :description
      t.string :image_url
      t.text :professor

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't see how to help with the information provided. Prove you have products by showing console output (redacted for space) of `Product.all`.

Comment: Please check in rails console output of Product.pluck(:name, :description) and let me know

Answer (score 0):

try to run in terminal `rake db:setup`

Though i think that,your products are temporary set in your app,and when you export it to git,you do not export the images,products as well,git avoid them to reduce memory.

Comment: Option I had ever tried , this is unfortunately not the solution for me

Answer (score 0):

In your views

`/app/views/products/index.html.erb`

it should be

```
   <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="large-9 small-12 column">
      <h3>
            <%= product.name %>
      </h3>
      <p class="label movie-label radius mb1">$ <%= product.price %></p>

      <p><%= product.description %></p>


    </div>
    <% end %>
```

you should not require below one

```
<%= render "product_index", product: @product, order_item: @order_item %>
```

and you should not require the partial view (`_product_index.html.erb`)
as it is showing product info what we did already above

Comment: thank you Rajarshi Das , but it don't fix the problem

Comment: Please check in `rails console` output of  `Product.pluck(:name, :description)` and let me know

Comment: 1.9.3-p551 :002 > Product.pluck(:name)
   (1.3ms)  SELECT `products`.`name` FROM `products`  WHERE `products`.`active` = 1
 => [nil, nil, nil] 
1.9.3-p551 :003 >  ok, here's the problem